# non-http in mochiweb

Tags: http, sockets, erlang, mochiweb

I am using mochiweb for a server that may also get a TCP connction to which the client sends a simple string (without a newline, the string is not http). Mochiweb uses HTTP sockets and therefore fails to detect this (i dont even get `http_error` that i can easily get in mochiweb). How can I solve this? Ideally I wish to change mochiweb code to do `setopt({packet, http_or_raw})` but this kind of thing does not exist. How would you recommend handling this? my current idea was to modify mochiweb and use `erlang:decode_packet`, is there a better approach?

EDIT:

More info.
Our server is a websocket service. We wish to allow
people without a ws supporting browser to use it so we use a
flash object to do websocket when the browser can't. The flash object needs to get a flash policy file. Flash
forces the file to be in one of two places:
- port 843 (flash hard coded)
- the port of the ws service
The flash protocol is NOT HTTP based.
Amazon ELB does not allow port forwarding for
most ports below 1024, so we
implemented the flash server in the same port via a patch to
mochiweb (https://github.com/nivertech/mochiweb/tree/ori_flash_170811).

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

mochiweb isn't designed to handle this use case, if it doesn't look
like HTTP then the connection is closed and it gets discarded. You
would have to go around mochiweb_http for this purpose. I'd suggest
using an alternate port, or making it look like HTTP.

If I really wanted to do what you say you want to do, I would copy
mochiweb_http.erl to some other name (e.g. sometimes_not_http.erl) and
make the appropriate changes to loop/2 and request/2… then instead of
adding mochiweb_http to your supervisor you'd add sometimes_not_http.
It is not necessary or recommended to make modifications to mochiweb
in-place.